# how to switch the database table in model based on condition in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

We have a table `consignments` which is having big data . so to keep our query quick we archive our old data to another table which is `archive_consignments` but in our consignment model I want that when I use eloquent like this

```
Consignment::find(1)
```

first it should try to get data from `consignments` table if it didn't found then it go to `archive_consignments`

is that possible to define this thing in eloquent model of `Consignment`

```
<?php

namespace App\Models\Admin;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Nicolaslopezj\Searchable\SearchableTrait;
use Staudenmeir\EloquentHasManyDeep\HasRelationships;
use Laravel\Scout\Searchable;


class Consignment extends Model
{
    // use SearchableTrait;
    use Searchable;
    use HasRelationships;

    protected $table = 'consignments';


    // following function to search by id(laravel scout)
    public function getScoutKey()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }
}
```

Comment: You could use the [Database: Query Builder](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#introduction) to write your queries

Comment: And what you will do if you need to join entities from two tables at same time? It’s wrong way.

Answer (score 0):

you could write using query builder

```
if(data not found in consignments )
{
     $data = \DB::table('archive_consignments')->here your conditiion to find data
}
```

hope this will be useful.

Comment: No i cant use it. we are using eloquent on 100 of places can't go there and put this condition

Answer (score 0):

What I would go with is to make ArchivedConsignment Model

Also I would make a function inside Repository that would be named something like queryConsignment and pass all my conditions as array for ex.

`[ 'where' => ['column' => 'name', 'value' => 'someName'], 'whereIn' => ['column' => 'name', 'value' =>['bla','bla'] ]`

Inside queryConsignment I would firstly call

`$query = Consignment::newQuery()`

after that I would apply all those conditions using a loop.

```
 foreach($conditons as $method => $conditon){
       $query->$method($condition['column'], $condition['value');
    }
$data = $query->first();
```

At the end if there is no entry inside Consignment I would do the same with ArchivedConsignment